# image represented as radix number in postscript

Tags: postscript

I would like to achive the same as this:

```
4 1 1 [1 0 0 1 0 0] {<4>} image
```

but using radix representation:

```
4 1 1 [1 0 0 1 0 0] 2#0100 image %this one does not work
```

Comment: If you just want to easily read and edit the bitmap's values, there is a way using names illustrated [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/Rvu76u4AxQU/discussion).

Comment: Here's an example very similar to what you're trying to do, but with a [3-bit RGB color image](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/UpaAZeNSKbo/fbr2xditBQAJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the PostScript Reference Manual:

> **image** *width height bits/sample matrix datasrc* **image** –
>
> [...]
>
> In LanguageLevel 1, *datasrc* must be a procedure. In LanguageLevel 2 or 3, it may be any data source—a procedure, a string, or a readable file, including a filtered file (see Section 3.13, “Filtered Files Details”).

`2#0100` is a number, but you need to supply a procedure, string or file.  There is no binary representation of strings, so you would have to implement your own conversion from a "binary string" to a "normal", hexadecimal or base-85 string.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a string dynamically

```
1 string  % str
```

and then put your value into it.

```
dup 0 2#100 put  % str'
```

And if you need level-1 compatibility, make a proc out of it.

```
{ 1 string dup 0 2#100put }
```

But, since the string is constant, it is wasteful to allocate a new one for each sample. So you can allocate it once, store it in the current dictionary, and use the name in the procedure.

```
/buf 1 string dup 0 2#100 put def

4 1 1 [1 0 0 1 0 0] {buf} image
```

And for an extra speed boost, factor-out the name-lookup as well.

```
4 1 1 [1 0 0 1 0 0] {//buf} image
```